# Get the object with the lowest value attribute from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know I can get the object with the lowest value attribute by executing

```
const obj = Math.min.apply(Math, myArr.map(o => { return o.val; }));
```

but I have to return the object, not the value of the object. How can I return the object from this?

My current way is

```
const lowest = (arr.sort((a, b) => a.val < b.val))[0];
```

but maybe there is a more optimized way.

Working example:

```js
function Obj(val) {
  this.val = val;
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  const data = [new Obj(2), new Obj(7), new Obj(9), new Obj(1), new Obj(3)];
  const lowestNumber = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(o => {
    return o.val;
  }));
  console.log(lowestNumber);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Not working:

```js
function Obj(val) {
  this.val = val;
}

$(document).ready(() => {
  const data = [new Obj(2), new Obj(7), new Obj(9), new Obj(1), new Obj(3)];
  const obj = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(o => {
    return o;
  }));
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This returns `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
const lowest = data.reduce((a, b) => a.val < b.val ? a : b);
```

The reduce function is used to "reduce" an array to a single value, based on comparisons between consecutive values. An extended explanation:

```
const lowest = data.reduce(
    function(a, b) {
        if (a.val < b.val) {
            // keep a as next value
            return a
        } else {
            // keep b as next value
            return b
        }
    })
```

Comment: This is plagiarism. GG.

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels Fair point. Extended explanation added

Comment: A bulletproof version would be: `data.reduce((a, b) => a && a.val < b.val ? a : b, undefined);`

Answer (score 3):

Since you want the object, and not the value, you cannot use `Math.min`.

For linear algo, use `reduce` instead:

```
const lowest = arr.reduce( (acc, a) => a.val < acc.val ? a : acc, arr[0]);
```

Comment: @Jorgo: it's OK now. All sorts of things happen on SO. I give you a constructive comment in exchange :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not well experienced with some special Math/Array functions, such easy task can be just implemented directly by you.

Sorting is not good way, if you have big arrays and you need reasonable performance.

```js
const arr = [ 
  { val: 3 },
  { val: 1 }
]

let minObj = arr[0];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.val < minObj.val) {
    minObj = obj;
  }
});

console.log(minObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also do it.. I believe this method has good performance too

```
var arr = [
    {"ID": "test1", "val": 1},
    {"ID": "test2", "val": 2},
    {"ID": "test3", "val": 3},
    {"ID": "test4", "val": 4}
]

arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
    return p.val < c.val ? p : c;
});
```